# XAML Binding to child collection

Tags: wpf, windows, xaml, binding, uwp

In a Windows UWP project I'm trying to bind to the following properties in this class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace IAmOkShared.Models
{
   public class Client
    {
        public Guid clientId { get; set; }
        public string lastname { get; set; }
        public DateTime timestamp { get; set; }

        //- List af addresses of this client
        public ObservableCollection<Address> clientaddresses;

        public Client ()
        {
            clientId = Guid.Empty;
            lastname = string.Empty;
            timestamp = DateTime.Today;

            clientaddresses = new ObservableCollection<Address>();
       }
    }
 }
```

Binding to clientId and lastname is no problem, but can't get it right to bind to one or more of the properties of clientaddresses (e.g city, country)

My XAML:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Name="DetailTemplate" x:DataType="models:Client">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock x:Name="LastNameTextBlock" Text="{Binding lastname}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock x:Name="AddressTextBlock" Text="{Binding clientaddresses[0].city}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Any idea how to solve this?
Steven

Comment: Binding clientaddresses[0].city will always bind to the first element in the collection, did you tried binding like Text="{Binding clientaddresses.city}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding to a **field** instead of a **property**.

```
public ObservableCollection<Address> clientaddresses;
```

Change this to

```
public ObservableCollection<Address> Clientaddresses { get; private set; }
```

So it cannot be instantiated outside the viewmodel then the binding should work.

Also you could create additional data template for the **Address** and just use the entire collection in your datatemplate of the **Client**, because then you would not get possible Index out of bounds exception if your ClientAddresses collection is empty.

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Address">
    <TextBlock x:Name="AddressTextBlock" Text="{Binding city}" />
<DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Name="DetailTemplate" x:DataType="models:Client">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock x:Name="LastNameTextBlock" Text="{Binding lastname}" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ClientAddresses}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Also note your model is not implementing the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) so your UI will not be updated when the model properties change.

Also the convention for back-end private fields is to start with lower case character and for the properties that utilize the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) you should start the property with upper case.

```
private int myProperty;
public int MyProperty { get { ... } set { ... }}
```

Answer (score 0):

that's why we create ViewModel and additional property in it

```
public Address ClientFirstAddress
{
    get {return clientaddresses[0].city;}
}
```

and then Bind it to View,
remember to call NofityPropertyChanged for this property when you set clientaddresses collection